# Why do non-exhaustive when expressions cause compiler error, but when statements don't?

Tags: kotlin

If I have a sealed class, for example

```kotlin
sealed class Result {
    object Success: Result()
    object Failure: Result()
}
```

Why do when statements compile when they are not exhaustive, but when expressions don't compile?

```
        when(getResult()) { //  `when` doesn't show a red squiggly, compiles file
            Result.Success -> {}
        }
        
        val result = when(getResult()) { // <--- when shows a red squiggly, doesn't compile
            Result.Success -> {}
        }
```

To make it a compile error for when statements, just call the exhaustive extension property:

```
        when(getResult()) { //  `when` NOW shows a red squiggly            
Result.Success -> {}
        }.exhaustive
```

I was watching [YouTube: Sealed classes - Kotlin Vocabulary](https://youtube.com/watch?v=OyIRuxjBORY) where they suggested using the following code to overcome this, but I want to understand why there is a difference. That should help me understand why the following Kotlin generic extension property solves the problem.

```kotlin
val <T> T.exhaustive: T
        get() = this
```

EDIT: Thanks to Tenfour04, I know **why**. I just don't know why this `exhaustive` extension function does its job.

Comment: Okay I think if it weren't exhaustive that would be dangerous. But can't you say the same about when expressions? What would we do? I guess its not dangerous, just **nothing** will happen.

Comment: Yes i totally understand that part now (I updated the question). But the reason why the `exhaustive` extension property adds the compile error is it turns the when statement into an expression? Not super clear whats going on there

Comment: I've added it, its actually just a 4 minute video, but basically calling `when(){}.exhaustive` makes it a compile error. Its a neat trick which I don't understand/ is not explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What would you expect to be assigned to result in the case where the result is not `Success`? The point of an expression is to evaluate to something. If you have cases where it doesn't evaluate to something, it would be like a function that has branches that don't return anything.

A statement doesn't have to return anything, so there's no reason it should be forced to. It's just like an `if` statement with no else branch in languages like C or Java. It's for when you want to do certain tasks only under certain conditions.

By calling something (a property in this case) on the result of a `when()`, you force the compiler to treat is as an expression instead of a statement. A statement doesn't evaluate to anything, so you can't call anything on its non-existent result.

The downside to this way of forcing exhaustive statements is that it creates a property that will appear in the autocomplete of absolutely everything. You could alternatively tag it with an empty scope function, but that looks kind of ugly.

```
when(getResult()) {
    Result.Success -> {}
}.run { }
```

Comment: Nice trick, I just used `run` its better than defining a extension property for everything, so I'll see how that goes through in my PR 

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin 1.6 [introduced the concept of "sealed `when` statements"](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/11/kotlin-1-6-0-is-released/#sealed-exhaustive-when-statements), which is what you're looking for. `when` statements on sealed classes, enums and booleans now report a warning if one of the branches is omitted. This will become an error in Kotlin 1.7.